# Sending game state only for entities that are "visible"?

Tags: sockets, networking, server, state, game-development

Let's say I have an open world game that supports multiple players.
The game stores their positioning by X and Y in this world.
Also, whoever is playing the game can see a canvas of 11x11, where his player-self is represented on this screen, always centered.
The game world has 1000x1000 squares to walk using keys.

**What I know is that:**

- I could emit events whenever a player walks,
- check this event data at the server-side (to see if it is possible and the speed is correct/anti-cheating measures),
- update the game state which contains all players and positioning,
- re-emit this state from the server so every client would be able to render properly this new player.

The problem is, should I really update someone who isn't even being seen?
When everyone is walking around, moving items, earning levels, etc - those events are being emitted from the client, and that's okay, but thinking about the server-side, it will re-emit that for each update state, and, maybe that will be overloaded?

Also, sending the whole game state, even if it isn't being rendered, opens so many breaches to cheating that this made me think that there is another option.

I'm a beginner at Networking and Game Development, and that is being hard to get into my mind - so I decided to try and put it into a question. This way, maybe with someone reading what I'm thinking about, I might get some clarification. Perhaps I'm just thinking about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *should I really update someone who isn't even being seen?*

There is no need.

The normal way MMORPG games do in the server side is to cyclely process network packages and some other calculations like the connection of players like skill cast or something else.

The central of a server may look like below

```
void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        processNetwork();
        processSkills();
        processMoves();
        ...
    }
}
```

The loop will run several times a second, like 20 frames a second is enough cause players can not feel the little frame, they think they move/play smoothly but the trueth is not.

For your question, player only need to see some little area, when he moves, the server will braodcast his postion to others in the area and the players in his area in the next frame.

And that is just the simpliest model, actual model will be more complicated and we will detach different functions of the game to different server, sucn as chat server, battle server, auction server and others.

Comment: Interesting. So instead of updating the state and emitting it for every update, I would have a loop that is saving this updated state and emitting it for those players in a certain loop, with, and only with information that they should actually receive about their zone. 
Thanks, man. Really helped a lot. It is good to see someone talking about it in some different words. 
Server architecture is something that amazes me, and I'll probably dive in to try something later about this, later on.

Comment: This architecture works on MMORPG game such as WOW, and this is mature. So I think this can help you.